# 'add-events-to-google-calendar' not showing correct date time in google event using angular 12

Tags: angular, calendar, google-calendar-api

I want to add google calendar in my angular project so I have tried [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/add-events-to-google-calendar)
add-events-to-google-calendar works well but it does not taking passed start time, end date and end time. only start date is taking right.

I searched on it but did not find any solution.

Basic code which is provided on link:

```
<app-add-to-calendar [startDate]='"8/25/2019"' [startTime]='"5:00 pm"' [endDate]='"8/25/2019"' [endTime]='"8:00 pm"' [title]='"Angular Google Event Component"' [details]='"Angular Google Event Component"' [location]='"The Bar, New York, NY"'></app-add-to-calendar>
```

Above code showing incorrect datetime like below:
[image]

It shows correct values when it creates URL to add event like below but not shows correct values in actual fields of google event.

**URL generated**

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/eventedit?text=Angular+Google+Event+Component&dates=20190825T170000Z/20190825T200000Z&details=Angular+Google+Event+Component&location=The+Bar,+New+York,+NY&sf=true&output=xml
```

I tried by matching timezone and passing dynamic values like below:

**Html file code**

```
<app-add-to-calendar
                          [startDate]="getCalenderDate(eventDetails.start_date)"
                          [startTime]="getCalenderTime(eventDetails.start_date)"
                          [endDate]="getCalenderDate(eventDetails.end_date)"
                          [endTime]="getCalenderTime(eventDetails.end_date)"
                          [title]="getValue(eventDetails.title)"
                          [details]="getValue(eventDetails.description)"
                          [location]="getValue(eventDetails.location)"
                        ></app-add-to-calendar>
```

**Ts file code**

```
getCalenderDate(eventDate){
    return formatDate(eventDate, 'M/d/yyyy', 'en-US', '+0530');
  }

  getCalenderTime(eventDate){
   return formatDate(eventDate, 'hh:mm a', 'en-US', '+0530');
  }

  getValue(value){
   return value;
  }
```

Above code also not shows correct date time in gmail event which are passed by attributes of code.

What should I do to get correct date time which are passed in gmail event to add it to calendar?
Is there any other package / way to add events to google calendar using angular?

Please help and guide.

Comment: what is the default time zone of the calendar in question?

Comment: @DaImTo My gmail account shows timezone - (GMT+05:30)India Standard Time-Kolkata. in package that I used there they have not mentioned how to set timezone.